# AWS s3 sftp without AWS transfer family

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp

Are there any other ways to upload files from an Ubuntu server to AWS s3 without AWS Transfer Family? I have to make a MYSQL dump every five minutes and upload to the bucket but the Transfer Family's hourly price is too high for the client.
Can i attach the storage to an EC2 and make an SFTP account on it?
The VPS which has the MYSQL is hosted by DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the AWS CLI v2 on your server(s) and use the CLI "aws s3 cp" [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) to upload the files to S3.

Doing a MySQL dump every give minutes seems excessive. You might be better syncing the MySQL binary / transaction logs to S3 every five minutes using "aws s3 sync" [CLI command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html), then doing a MySQL dump daily. You can use S3 lifecycle policies to delete the transaction logs from S3 after a week or so.

Whichever method you use, make sure you schedule regular restore tests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah, AWS CLI works like a charm. MY client is paranoid so i have to backup every five minutes then need to cp the bin log too.

Comment: RDS is probably going to be cheaper / easier than running a database on EC2, given the amount of S3 storage you'll probably use. RDS does backups to S3 every 5 minutes, and generally it's a managed database that is simpler than rolling your own. It may give your client more peace of mind and make your life easier.

Comment: The vps is on digitalocean. The s3 price will be ~$1/month. Anyway, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Suggest you consider backing up the binary logs rather than doing a full MySQL dump. I'm not a DBA, but I think daily full backups and then keeping the binary logs backed up is probably sufficient and much more efficient.